# Laravel lighthouse inject nested mutations

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Here are my inputs for nested mutation:

```
input ActivityInput {
  id: ID
  user_id: ID
  goal: String
}

input ActivityRelationInput {
  upsert: [ActivityInput]
  delete: [ID]
}

input CustomerInput {
  id: ID
  name: String
  activities: ActivityRelationInput
}
```

And here is my mutation:

```
extend type Mutation {
  customerUpsert(input: CustomerInput! @spread): Customer
  @upsert(model: "App\\Models\\Customer")
  @inject(context: "user.id" name: "activities.upsert[].user_id")
}
```

I need to inject `user.id` into `Activity` input, but don't know how to use `@inject` for array inputs. I've tried the code above but didn't succeed. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: `@inject` is a [repeatable directive](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/0d8f0fb8a3dd2791dda4c772f3db4b53ee072fb3/src/Schema/Directives/InjectDirective.php#L34), so you should be able to use it multiple times.

Comment: @AlexBouma how can I use `@inject` for array input?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution for your problem, but it could be a workaround:

I was facing a similar problem.
To write a Chat-Message the user updates the Chat by adding a new Message and i want to inject the user.id from context as author_id.

Using lighthouse [@nest directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#nest) did the job for me.

```
updateChat(id: ID! @eq input: ChatOperations @nest): Chat @update @inject(context: "user.id" name:"input.newMessage.author_id")
```

The Chat operations input:

```
inputChatOperations {
    newMessage: CreateMessageInput @create(relation: "messages")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer but I am having difficulties implementing this. Any chance you can give a but more details? Thanks!

Comment: I think I was able to implement this. Now I have to figure out how to do this with an array of object in the nested mutation.

Comment: Nice to hear! Let us know if you find a solution for arrays pls. Unfortunately, I haven't found one yet

Comment: I think the solution is here : https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/issues/1879. But I haven't been able to implement this. Good luck if you give it a shot :)